# Is there a clearer version of Giuseppe Piazzi's complete set of observations for the discovery of Ceres?

Tags: raw-data

The image below comes from [the paper Giuseppe Piazzi and the Discovery of Ceres G . Foderà Serio](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Giuseppe-Piazzi-and-the-Discovery-of-Ceres-G-.-Piazzi-Serio/827c80013f77607d0aedcfd98dc7f6420fbaab50), which is too blurry to read. Is there a clearer version of this table or digital tabular form like .csv or something?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to find better images if you Google for the original source of Figure 3, meaning search for "Monatliche Correspondenz, September 1801, p. 280"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data in tabular CSV form. Refer to [Prallax's answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/45219/10172) for the schema.

```
"Jan", 1,8,43,17.8,3,27,11.25,51,47,48.8,15,37,43.5,1,23,22,58.3,3, 6,42.1, 9,11, 1,30.9,9.9926156
"Jan", 2,8,39, 4.6,3,26,53.85,51,43,27.8,15,41, 5.5,1,23,19,44.3,3, 2,24.9, 9,12, 2,28.6,9.9926317
"Jan", 3,8,34,53.3,3,26,38.4 ,51,39,36.0,15,44,31.6,1,23,16,58.6,2,58, 9.9, 9,13, 3,26.6,9.9926324
"Jan", 4,8,30,42.1,3,26,23.15,51,35,47.3,15,47,57.6,1,23,14,15.5,2,53,55.6, 9,14, 4,24.9,9.9926418
"Jan",10,8, 6,15.8,3,25,32.1 ,51,23, 1.5,16,10,32.0,1,23, 7,59.1,2,29, 0.6, 9,20,10,17.5,9.9927641
"Jan",11,8, 2,17.5,3,25,29.73,51,22,26.0,  ,  ,    , ,  ,  ,    , ,  ,    ,  ,  ,  ,    ,
"Jan",13,7,54,26.2,3,25,30.30,51,22,34.5,16,22,49.5,1,23,10,27.6,2,16,59.7, 9,23,12,13.8,9.9928490
"Jan",14,7,50,31.7,3,25,31.72,51,22,55.8,16,27, 5.7,1,23,12, 1.2,2,12,56.7, 9,24,14,13.5,9.9928809
"Jan",17, ,  ,    ,3,25,     ,  ,  ,    ,16,40,13.0, ,  ,  ,    , ,  ,    ,  ,  ,  ,    ,
"Jan",18,7,35,11.3,3,25,55   ,51,28,45.0,  ,  ,    , ,  ,  ,    , ,  ,    ,  ,  ,  ,    ,
"Jan",19,7,31,28.5,3,26, 8.15,51,32, 2.3,16,49,16.1,1,23,25,59.2,1,53,38.2, 9,29,19,53.8,9.9930607
"Jan",21,7,24, 2.7,3,26,34.27,51,38,34.1,16,58,35.9,1,23,34,21.3,1,46, 6.0,10, 1,20,40.3,9.9931434
"Jan",22,7,20,21.7,3,26,49.42,51,42,21.3,17, 3,18.5,1,23,39, 1.8,1,42,28.1,10, 2,21,32.0,9.9931886
"Jan",23,7,16,43.5,3,27, 6.90,51,46,43.5,17, 8, 5.5,1,23,44,15.7,1,38,52.1,10, 3,22,22.7,9.9932348
"Jan",28,6,58,51.3,3,28,54.55,52,13,38.3,17,32,54.1,1,24,15,15.7,1,21, 6.9,10, 8,26,20.1,9.9935062
"Jan",30,6,51,52.9,3,29,48.14,52,27, 2.1,17,43,11.0,1,24,30, 9.0,1,14,16.0,10,10,27,46.2,9.9936332
"Jan",31,6,48,25.4,3,30,17.25,52,34,18.8,17,48,21.5,1,24,38, 7.3,1,10,54.6,10,11,28,28.5,9.9937007
"Feb", 1,6,44,59.9,3,30,47.2 ,52,41,48.0,17,53,36.5,1,24,46,19.3,1, 7,30.9,10,12,29, 9.6,9.9937703
"Feb", 2,6,41,35.8,3,31,19.06,52,49,45.9,17,58,57.5,1,24,54,57.9,1, 4,10.5,10,13,29,49.9,9.9938423
"Feb", 5,6,31,31.5,3,33, 2.70,53,15,40.5,18,15, 1.0,1,25,22,43.4,0,54,28.9,10,16,31,45.5,9.9940751
"Feb", 8,6,21,39.2,3,34,58.50,53,44,37.5,18,31,23.2,1,25,53,29.5,0,45, 5.0,10,19,33,33.3,9.9943276
"Feb",11,6,11,58.2,3,37, 6.54,54,16,38.1,18,47,58.8,1,26,26,40.0,0,36, 2.9,10,22,35,11.4,9.9945823
```

Comment: wow, how did you do that?

Comment: and how did you *check it?*

Answer (score 9):

Following JohnHoltz's wise advice, here it is:
https://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/receive/jportal_jparticle_00316276

[image]